# Cant run .py File, but the same runs if i run it as a script after installing anaconda in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk, anaconda

I installed anaconda for IntroML course of udacity. But now after that i cannot run .py files as is, i have to run it as script. Also print text gives error, it requires print (text) although it is python 2.7

The screenshot for the same is here

[image]

I am new to python as well as ML. Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
from nltk.stem import *
import string

def parseOutText(f):
    """ given an opened email file f, parse out all text below the
        metadata block at the top
        (in Part 2, you will also add stemming capabilities)
        and return a string that contains all the words
        in the email (space-separated) 

        example use case:
        f = open("email_file_name.txt", "r")
        text = parseOutText(f)

        """


    f.seek(0)  ### go back to beginning of file (annoying)
    all_text = f.read()

    ### split off metadata
    content = all_text.split("X-FileName:")
    words = ""
    #print (content)
    if len(content) > 1:
        ### remove punctuation
        text_string = content[1].translate(string.maketrans("", ""), string.punctuation)

        ### project part 2: comment out the line below
        words = text_string
        print (words)
        ### split the text string into individual words, stem each word,
        ### and append the stemmed word to words (make sure there's a single
        ### space between each stemmed word)
        stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english", ignore_stopwords=True)
        words =  text_string.split(" ")
        # print (words)
        print (len(words))
        words = [stemmer.stem(x) for x in words if len(x) > 0]
        # print (words)
        print (len(words))

    return ' '.join(words)



def main():
    ff = open("../text_learning/test_email.txt", "r")
    text = parseOutText(ff)
    print (text)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is your issue simply that you can't run any .py file or is it this one particularly? What specifically does work and what doesn't? Try to provide a [mcve] instead of that code; break it into something simple that shows your issue so that we can be of more help.

Comment: Sir, whenever i have some import statement in my python file, then this No Module error is thrown. Is it because i installed anaconda in ubuntu? because previously it worked fine

Comment: It's because of this at the top of your file: `#!/usr/bin/python` This calls the system version of Python, which may not have all your packages installed